# Failed to run custom action. Couldn't connect to the server at 'http://localhost:5055/webhook'

Tags: python, rasa

i am trying to test my rasa bot, by running `rasa shell` , and before that i run `rasa run actions` i run both cmds in different anaconda prompte , but when i try to test using rasa shell, i got this error

````
2021-09-13 16:39:15 INFO     root  - Starting Rasa server on http://localhost:5005
2021-09-13 16:39:30 INFO     rasa.nlu.components  - Added 'SpacyNLP' to component cache. Key 'SpacyNLP-fr'.
2021-09-13 16:39:36 INFO     rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - MappingPolicy not included in policy ensemble. Default intents 'restart and back will not trigger actions 'action_restart' and 'action_back'.
Bot loaded. Type a message and press enter (use '/stop' to exit):
Your input ->  00
2021-09-13 16:45:01 ERROR    rasa.core.actions.action  - Failed to run custom action 'action_menu'. Couldn't connect to the server at 'http://localhost:5055/webhook'. Is the server running? Error: Cannot connect to host localhost:5055 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5055)]
2021-09-13 16:45:01 ERROR    rasa.core.processor  - Encountered an exception while running action 'action_menu'. Bot will continue, but the actions events are lost. Please check the logs of your action server for more information.```
````

Answer (score 0):

Are you able please to share the logs in the Terminal window where you're running the `rasa run actions` command? Also please confirm that you've uncommented this section in `endpoints.yml`:

```
action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **endpoints.yml**, did you uncomment the following two lines?

```
action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"
```

Also try to open cmd prompt as an admin.

Moreover, I hope you are using the latest version of Rasa and the actions.py file. Because there is a similar problem when you use the outdated version of actions.py.